# Traditional Radio Buttons vs Bootstrap Styled Primary-Secondary Toggle Buttons

Tags: radio-buttons, webforms

For a responsive web form I am considering two options for radio buttons with three or fewer selections.

I personally like the bootstrap css style format because it seems easier for the user on mobile and appears like a more modern UX design.  I've seen many websites in my industry moving to these type of bootstrap button selections on web forms:

[image]

My designer said it is not the best UX practice to use the above type of buttons.  It was indicated that I should use the traditional radio buttons like below (either vertical or horizontal). I feel these are harder for the user, especially on a smaller mobile screen.

[image]

Is one method better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is one method better than the other?*

As with most things in UX design, we need to be able to set some objectives to measure both options against each other.

**Responsiveness**:
The traditional radio button would scale better with additional options or longer texts. It also doesn't require additional engineering work to control the display.
[image]

However, the modern option would require special treatment once the number of options becomes more or the text within the options become longer.
[image]

**Accessibility**:
Radio buttons are generally more accessible since they have been around longer and [most screen readers can read the value within the HTML code](https://a11y-101.com/development/radio-buttons), I cannot say the same for the modern alternative option you have proposed.

**Readability**:
It's generally harder to scan things horizontally, especially when you have more than 2 options. It's not impossible but the vertical listing is the most expected by users.

**Usability**:
From your example, it's hard to know what the clicked state for the modern selection would look like. But [I checked bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/), and this is what you will get if you have just 2 options. With this, it's really unclear what option is the chosen one in the modern selection controls.
[image]

**But you can merge the best of both worlds.** By combining the aesthetic appeal of the modern version, with the enduring usability of the traditional approach.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with your designer.

Your first example may confuse users as it is not easy to differentiate between the options. It looks like 1 option.

[image]

With radio buttons, it is very clear to the user what the options are.

[image]
[image]

Here is an excellent resource with some great examples:

https://www.justinmind.com/blog/radio-button-design-examples/